# How to load fall back for different jQuery plugins when CDN is down

Tags: javascript, jquery, cdn, content-delivery-network, jquery-confirm

Ok, I am going through one tutorial and it teaches that if jQuery CDN is down use below code as fallback

```
<script>
window.jQuery || document.write('Actual Location of jQuery in the VS solution file')
</script>
```

But I am confused how does the name `window.jQuery` is determined for different jQuery Plugins. I mean what if CDN is down for [jQuery Confirm PlugIn](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.2.3/jquery-confirm.min.js). Then what shall I put instead of `window.jQuery`. Please guide me.

Does the name `window.jQuery` accounts for all the different jQuery plugins? I doubt it though.

**For instance:** Since every plugin has it's own CDN. What if the CDN for jQuery is wokring fine but the CDN for some other jQuery plugin is down.

Comment: this will not works with the plugins you could use. You will have to set different tests for each one you use.

Comment: But how to put different test. What shall I put for, for example the plug in I mentioned in the question. `window.jQuery` should be replaced with what?

Comment: From the doc: http://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/#usage , for this plugin you can test if `$.confirm` is defined.

Comment: Is this really even an issue? How often does your "cdn go down", and for how long? If the answer is "frequently enough to care", change CDNs, or just use local copies. This seems like an imagined problem.

Comment: I am a beginner so I asked for learning purpose. Thanks for your reply though. I was just curious.

Comment: Ok, in that case, the code you show checks *if jQuery itself* has been defined, not its plugins. If you want to check if your specific plugin is defined, you could do `if( typeof jQuery.confirm === 'function'){ // do stuff with confirm plugin }` but as far as actually loading an alternate version, I still say, that's not really an issue.

Comment: And yes, you would have to do the above for every plugin individually using a function name that is unique to each plugin if that's what you are after. But again, IMHO you dont really need a solution until an actual problem presents and even if you did have issues changing cdns or using local files would be a far more appropriate solution.

Comment: Aye sire! Understood. :)